# Access query: Where IIF function

Tags: ms-access, where-clause, iif

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    invoice.number,
    invoice.amount,
    invoice.paid, 
    iif (invoice.paid='Y', Max(payments.datePay), '') as invoice_paid
FROM 
    payments 
    INNER JOIN 
    invoice
    ON (invoices.number = payments.numberDoc AND payments.type = 'Invoice')
WHERE 
    payments.type= 'Invoice'
GROUP BY
    number, 
    amount,
    paid
```

Runs fine.

Sample results:

```
number   |  amount  | paid | invoice_paid

00000003 |  347,94€ |   Y |    23/05/2014

00000004 |  462,65€ |   N | 

00000005 |  462,65€ |   Y | 13/08/2014

00000006 |  453,88€ |   Y | 03/09/2014

00000007 |  155,57€ |   Y | 04/09/2014

00000008 |  500,00€ |   N |
```

But now I need to **filter by "invoice_paid" date.**

If I execute this:

```
SELECT 
    invoice.number,
    invoice.amount,
    invoice.paid, 
    iif (invoice.paid='Y', Max(payments.datePay), '') as invoice_paid
FROM 
    payments 
    INNER JOIN 
    invoice
    ON (invoices.number = payments.numberDoc AND payments.type = 'Invoice')
WHERE 
    payments.type= 'Invoice' AND invoice_paid=#01/01/2014#
GROUP BY
    number, 
    amount,
    paid
```

display window: "introduce parameter invoice_paid".

How I can filter the results by the result returned by iif function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are accurate, but let me try to clarify something for you, then ask a question...

The column you are computing for "invoice_paid" can't be used in the where clause by it's alias result column, you would have to use the raw original date from the table itself, such as

```
WHERE payments.type= 'Invoice' AND payments.datePay=#01/01/2014#
```

And you can't use an aggregate such as MAX( payments.datepay ) in the where clause either, that would have to be in the HAVING clause after the GROUPING clause as noted by user iDevlop.

You have a filter for a specific date (based on = ), yet none of your data shows such a date.  So, not only would this probably not return results (or very little) by either WHERE or HAVING method.  If you are looking for payments for a specific date, I would just query that directly and show.

Now, the question.  Do you only want the one date or did you really mean to get anything that has an invoice with a max( datePay ) GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO Jan 1, 2014?  If so, change the equality test to >= #01/01/2014#

Comment: I think that this "WHERE payments.type= 'Invoice' AND payments.datePay=#01/01/2014#" will not return the data that I need. I do not want to filter by payment.datePaid, but the result of the iif function, which is different. each invoice can have several payments. And I'm only interested in the last payment of each invoice. is the date showed in column 'invoice_paid' when invoice is paid.

Comment: forget my last comment. your answer is correct :-) works fine.

Comment: @kontable, then you want the HAVING clause, but not sure the date range vs = vs >= condition

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the whole expression in the WHERE condition, simply using the alias will not work, but will result in the enter parameter value box. So either,

```
SELECT 
    invoice.[number],
    invoice.[amount],
    invoice.[paid], 
    IIF (invoice.paid='Y', Max(payments.datePay), '') as invoice_paid
FROM 
    payments 
    INNER JOIN 
    invoice
    ON (invoices.number = payments.numberDoc AND payments.type = 'Invoice')
WHERE 
    payments.type= 'Invoice' 
    AND 
    IIF (invoice.paid='Y', Max(payments.datePay), '') = #01/01/2014#
GROUP BY
    [number], 
    [amount],
    [paid]
```

Or create a Query, and create another Query based on this Query to get the right data. Or SubQuery.

Comment: i tried but returns error: Cannot have aggregate function in WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want a `WHERE` here, but rather a `HAVING`, since you want to filter on a value AFTER aggregation.

Try using :

```
where payments.type='Invoice'
GROUB BY ...
HAVING iif(invoice.paid='Y',max(payments.datePay),'') = #01/01/2014#
```

Comment: returns error: Does Not Include The Specified Expression as an Aggregate Function